# App working on dialogflow but not on Actions on Google Simulator

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Recently, I have launched an app named 'Voice Cricket' on the google assistant skill store and it has been deployed successfully. I was trying to implement new features in the app, but when I tested my app successfully on dialogflow test console, I shifted over to Actions on Google simulator where I am getting this error

> expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: 'rich_response'
>   must contain at least one item.

with response as

```
Voice Cricket isn't responding right now. Try again soon.
```

And now, I am unable to play the game on my device(getting same response as above) which is linked to the same google account on which I am building the app but when I tried playing the app on my friend's phone, it was working perfectly.

What could be the scenario? Where I might be wrong?

I even tried printing the logs on the firebase console which I am using in my app, but none is being shown.

P.S. - I am also confused about the status shown on my assistant console which is 'Deployed' but according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#deployment_states), these can be possible status of your app, in which 'Deployed' is not one of them. Why is it so?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time in an SO question. If you have multiple questions - asking them separately is typically the best approach. Can you also update your question to include the results of the "response" and "debug" tabs? Do you have stackdriver logging turned on for your Dialogflow project? If so, can you include those logs as well?

Comment: If you are using firebase, you should see with 'npm run logs' which intent you triggered and maybe even an error. This error comes when your app doesn't answer anything or there is an error in what you answered.

Comment: @Prisoner 
I identified the problem i.e. I was using google suggestion chips in Default Welcome Intent and therefore this error was shown to me. Now I am able to run the app in AoG simulator.

Comment: Are you using `dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs`? If yes, the error could be due to this issue. https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/187